# How to href or link a html sheet with div's and ul's

Tags: html, href

My html page has a div that has hundreds of lines (ul, li) describing a list of checkboxes. I'd like to save those lines into an external html sheet, and reference them with href or similar to free up space. I've tried using link and anchor but no luck as I'm a beginner. Here's the code from the external html sheet:

```
     <div id="checklist"  >
        <div id="info">&nbsp;</div> 

     <!-- this part has 100's of ul and li tags -->

     </div>
```

How would I reference the entire sheet? Thanks

Edit: so far I've tried using this to no avail:

```
<link href="file:///D:/externalsheets/checklist.html" rel="stylesheet" >
```

..which should have linked to another html sheet containing the div's.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show what you have, what you'd like, and what you've done.

Comment: Basically I want to cut out all the code from the question above, paste it into an external sheet, and somehow link that sheet into the original sheet. I put an edit in

Comment: I suggest storing the list items in another format, possibly JSON, then use a template to render all of the items (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Are you asking for an iframe? Pretty much a div but the content is drawn from an outside source such as a website or .html file.

Comment: If they all have ids, use `file:///D:/externalsheets/checklist.html#info` as a format

Comment: What you're looking for is [**HTML imports**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) it's still not widely supported yet http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports, instead you might use AJAX or an iframe or a server side language like `include('sidebar.html');` in PHP